# manage.py runserver do nothing on VPS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, openssl

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` on Ubuntu 16.04 VPS machine it does nothing with my project but it runs that runs on my computer.

I try to run `python3 -v manage.py runserver` and have seen that it stopped when executing this:

```
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__pycache__/SSL.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'OpenSSL.SSL' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x2b1d1d937630>
# /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__pycache__/version.cpython-35.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/version.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__pycache__/version.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'OpenSSL.version' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x2b1d1e6a5c50>
import 'OpenSSL' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x2b1d1d923da0>
```

after last line it start to do nothing

my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for hahachat project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '............'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'main',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',
    'channels',
    'room',
    'chat',
    'game',
    'living_room',
    'api',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hahachat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hahachat/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

os.environ['REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://h:p86b9c0868bee0a41b875b4ea3c31db8dd8744d988a6ab8678936814a3e09e93a@ec2-54-82-84-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:13629'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hahachat.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'hahachat.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        # 'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [
                # ('redis://:admin@redis-19717.c74.us-east-1-4.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com', 19717),
                # ('redis://h:p86b9c0868bee0a41b875b4ea3c31db8dd8744d988a6ab8678936814a3e09e93a@ec2-54-82-84-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 13629),
                # ('ec2-54-82-84-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 13629)
                # ('127.0.0.1', 6379),
                os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://redis:6379')
                ],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hahachat/static/'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hahachat/media/')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.HahaUser'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/.*$'

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'No-no-no:)'  # change it for stackoveflow
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'No-no-no:)' # change it for stackoveflow

# rest framework confuguration
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra lookup directories for collectstatic to find static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

#  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I try to create another project and it runs perfectly, so the problem is in my project, can you help me?)

UPD

Now when I trying to do `pip3 list` it's stacked too on importing cryptography module

```
import 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.scrypt' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x2ac73f3a9588>
```

Comment: You [shouldn't be using `manage.py runserver` in production anyway](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#runserver): "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)" Consider switching to a real WSGI server like Gunicorn, uwsgi, or Waitress and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: (Also, you should probably generate a new [`SECRET_KEY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY) now that you've posted yours for everybody to see.)

Comment: i try to do this with other servers and have the same results, now I have the same troubles even when I run pip3 list but it stopped on importing cryptography module.

Comment: How are you managing your Python environment? Are you using a virtualenv? Do you have your dependencies defined in a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: I use venv my dependecies defined in requirements.txt but i had installed it by errors because it seems that in requiremets are useless libraries, after installing channels project cant run(

Comment: Well it sounds like something might be wrong there. Have you locked down your versions? Have you tried running on your machine in a brand new, clean virtualenv? Are you using the same version of Python in both places?

Comment: All is ok, I fix it by deleting problem files

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very good solution... did you create your virtualenv directly on the server, or copy it from somewhere else?

Comment: It works fine for now, I don't see any issues, create venv on server

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by deleting files that cause problems.